Repeating Program c#
I have this C# and it is a login program. It works like this:
The program asks you to enter specific TAG and if you get it wrong you have to put in a password to find your tag.
If enter right password you enter the team. If you don't get the password right you have to restart program (this is the problem).
And if you get the password right and the team right you get your tag and restart program.
If you enter your team wrong you also have to restart program.
But instead of reopening the program I want so I press a button and it will print out the same program again.
Here is the code
using System;

namespace GOVERMENTPROGRAM
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
              Console.WindowWidth = 70;
              Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO THE A.A.A.R GOVERMENT (Sniper) PROGRAM TO ACCESS INFORMATION\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT INFORMATION");
              Console.Write("TAG:");
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
              String TAG = (Console.ReadLine());
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
              if (TAG == "A.A.A_ter5"){
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome Sniper #5");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("MISSION OF THE DAY:");
                Console.WriteLine("A new cocaine drug dealer is trending in the city");
                Console.WriteLine("Your job is too assasinate his team and call our organization");
              }
              else {
                Console.WriteLine("That Does Not exist");
                Console.Write("Enter Organization password to reveal TAGS\nPASSWORD:");
              }
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
              String password = (Console.ReadLine());
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
              if (password == "231234TER"){
                Console.Write("TEAM(IN XXX):");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                String TEAM = (Console.ReadLine());
                if (TEAM == "SNIPER") {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("A.A.A_ter1\nA.A.A_ter2");
                    Console.WriteLine("A.A.A_ter3\nA.A.A_ter4");
                    Console.WriteLine("A.A.A_ter5");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please close program to restart LOGIN");
                }
                else{
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong, software login is built for specific team and you are not on that team");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter TOR to restart LOGIN");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    String TOR = (Console.ReadLine());
                    while (TOR == "TOR"){
                
              }

                }
              }
              else {
                  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                  Console.WriteLine("WRONG");
                  Console.WriteLine("Please Enter TER  to restart LOGIN");
              }
              String TER = (Console.ReadLine());
              Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
              while (TER == "TER"){
                
              }

              Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

Please someone tell me how to achieve this

There is a while loop at the end, so you should be familiar with the concept of loops? - You are going to need one around the whole thing.

just put the entire code within your main-function into a big while-loop, that terminates, when user-input is some specific string, for instance.

Just for clarity.  "restarting the program" would mean the physically program ends, and then must be started again.  This is not what you want.  You want to "repeat" part of or all of the program again.  As mentioned look at using a while loop, then also moving parts of your code into separate methods will help with the structure.

You can use a while loop:
Example:
bool state = true;

    while (state) 
    {
       // Your logic
       state = false; // To drop out of the loop (if needed)
    }

Example how I would've solved it (even though I had problems understanding what you wrote, sorry to say that but your requirements need to be more clear):
namespace GOVERMENTPROGRAM
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WindowWidth = 70;

            Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO THE A.A.A.R GOVERMENT (Sniper) PROGRAM TO ACCESS INFORMATION\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT INFORMATION");
            Lore();
        }

        static void Lore()
        {
            bool state = true;

            while (state)
            {
                Console.Write("TAG:");

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

                string TAG = (Console.ReadLine());

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                if (TAG == "A.A.A_ter5")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome Sniper #5");

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                    Console.WriteLine("MISSION OF THE DAY:");
                    Console.WriteLine("A new cocaine drug dealer is trending in the city");
                    Console.WriteLine("Your job is too assasinate his team and call our organization");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That Does Not exist");
                    state = false;
                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

                Console.Write("Enter Organization password to reveal TAGS\nPASSWORD:");
                string password = (Console.ReadLine());

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                if (password == "231234TER")
                {
                    Console.Write("TEAM(IN XXX):");

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

                    string TEAM = (Console.ReadLine());

                    if (TEAM == "SNIPER")
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                        Console.WriteLine("A.A.A_ter1\nA.A.A_ter2");
                        Console.WriteLine("A.A.A_ter3\nA.A.A_ter4");
                        Console.WriteLine("A.A.A_ter5");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please close program to restart LOGIN");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong, software login is built for specific team and you are not on that team");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter TOR to restart LOGIN");

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

                        string TOR = Console.ReadLine(); 
                        state = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("WRONG");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter TER  to restart LOGIN");

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

                    string TER = (Console.ReadLine());
                    state = false;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Reset();
        }

        static void Reset()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
  
            Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO THE A.A.A.R GOVERMENT (Sniper) PROGRAM TO ACCESS INFORMATION\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT INFORMATION");
            Lore();
        }
    }
}

Everything should work except the format, but that was not the question. I believe that there are many tutorials for formatting console output and that they can be found all over the net.
One major thing you should learn is to start using separate methods. I don't know if you already used separate methods before but they can be really important, especially when it comes to code readability!
Don't forget that there are more ways to achieve this. You could also use for(;;). Both will do the same thing when checking in CIL.
